# Каково предназначение этого кода?

Tags: php

Засел разбирать opencart, наткнулся на нечто вовсе не понятное:

```
    $globals = array($_REQUEST, $_SESSION, $_SERVER, $_FILES);
    foreach ($globals as $global) {
            foreach(array_keys($global) as $key) {
                unset(${$key}); 
            }
        }
```

Зачем это может быть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это чтобы были удалены все переменные, совпадающие именем с ключом суперглобальных массивов. Зачем - другой вопрос. Скорее всего, в целях безопасности: 4 PHP при GET запросе создавал переменную именно с таким именем.

Собственно, конструкция

```
${$key}
```

- это более правильный вариант $$key с принудительным переводом значения переменной $key в строку и попыткой найти переменную с таким именем.

Comment: конструкция понятна, да и потенциольно уязвимые globals уже увидел. спасибо!